# Is there a champion that can outrange turrets without Firecannon?

Tags: league-of-legends

In Dota2 there is a hero (or multiple, I don't know exactly) that can out-range a turret. Is there a champion in League of Legends that can out-range a turret?

I'm looking for answers that don't include the Firecannon as that item was made to out-range turrets.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> All turrets have 1095 sight range and 775 attack range[1]

So the question is: are there any champions with an attack range higher then 775.

> Each champion begins the game with a particular base autoattack range. This can vary from 125 to 200 for melee units and 400 to 650 for ranged units. The highest base autoattack range for champions is held by Caitlyn. At level 18, **the highest autoattack range is 669 held by Tristana** surpassing Caitlyn at level 16 with 650 autoattack range. This is because of Tristana's  Draw a Bead.[2]

Sounds like there is no one with a base basic attack range higher then 775.
However:

> Twitch's Rat-Ta-Tat-Tat increases his attack range to **850** from 550 for 7 seconds.[2]

So Twitch's ult should be able to out range an turret.

I have no tested this.
**EDIT:** gnarly 404 just tested this.

Source:
[1] http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Turret
[2] http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Range

Comment: Hmm, Im going to try that. I did already know you can hit both nexus turrets with Twitch's Rat-Ta-Tat-Tat.

Comment: Allright, seems Twitch can backdoor without using minions. His Ambush and the Youmoo's active make him drop turrets really fast. Yi and Jax might learn something from a smelly rat.

Comment: I remember Tristana being able to do it, but that was years ago... might have nerfed her

Comment: Tristana can't do it, the only one that can is Twitch

Comment: It does outrange it, but the duration wont be long enough to successfully kill a turret from full hp

Comment: And to outrange turret with Rapid fire cannon you must have more than 625 range.

Comment: Last I checked, I can shoot a turret with Cait once and not get shot by the turret. As of maybe patch 6.12 or somewhere around there.

Answer (score 3):

Senna, *as of patch v10.20*, can damage a turret outside its range with enough Absolution (passive) stacks.

Considering a turret's attack range is 750 and Senna's base attack range for Piercing Darkness (Q) is 600, it takes 120 Absolution stacks to have the same attack range of a turret and 140 to outrange it, since Senna gains 25 bonus range for every 20 stacks.

Answer (score 2):

In this patch no, the only one that used to do it was tristana but they nerfed it.

You can compare every range with tower range and you'll see that noone outrange towers.

bonus : Still, some adc like caitlyn or tristana have higher range that allows to hit baron nashor or drake from the other side of the pit using specific spots.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there are champions, this patch, that can outrange a turret.
When they came out with rapid-fire cannon, the picture they used for an example of it was Tristana, firing a shot at a turret from way out of its range.
Although, I believe there are a few champions who come very close:

- Jinx (when using fishbones, she can hit the turret from the very edge of the turret range)
- Tristana
- Twitch (according to the answer above)
- Caitlyn, pretty high range, but I haven't tested how ranged she actually is, but she starts out with the highest base auto attack range in the game, surpassed by tristana later in-game.

Comment: I tested it with Twitch after I saw that answer and I could safely destroy turrets with his ultimate.

Answer (score -2):

Kindred with enough stacks can because they are infinite.

Comment: Not possible without RFC.

Comment: The attack range boost caps at +250 range, which brings her total attack range to 750. This is just shy of a tower's range (775), so unfortunately Kindred cannot outrange turrets.